# how can we convert Multi-value fields as normal fields (as strings or numbers) like Text/Dimension Field to be consumed at Table

Tags: einstein-analytics, einstein-analytics-dashboards, crm-analytics, release-notes, feature-activation

RE : Multi-Value Field conversion:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_bi_saql_mv_to_string.htm&release=228&type=5

I am not able to use "Convert Multi-Value Fields to String Fields in SAQL" function even after changing all the essential configurations.

Comment: Do you have Analytics Platform license configured?

Comment: Yes, I do have license configured.